# Copying database to cloned server and keeping both copies?

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, restore

I'm in a rather odd situation. At my work, we have two MSSQL 2012 servers, one physically hosted here, one virtual. Through a long, frustrating set of circumstances, our migration plans fell apart and we now have both servers with different data on each. I have to take a database, let's call it cms1, from the physical server and move it to the virtual server. However, I have to also make sure the virtual server's copy of cms1 remains intact, then run a script to move the changed tables from one to the other.

What I've tried so far is:

1. Make a full back up of the physical server's copy into cms1.bak, then copy that bak file over to the virtual server.
2. Rename the virtual server's version of the database with "alter database cms1 modify name = cms1_old". Good so far.
3. Take the newly renamed cms1_old db offline, then restore from my bak file. I get an error that the file for cms1 (NOT cms_old) is in use.
4. I went to the actual location on disk and renamed the two files associated with cms1 to be cms1_old. I closed SSMS and re-opened it, and tried the restore again. I got the same error, that the file for cms1 (again, NOT the file for cms1_old) was in use.
5. (update) I have since discovered detaching databases and tried to use that. When re-attaching after renaming the files for cms1_old, though, SSMS says that the files cannot be found. I believe I've gotten every path correct, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Was my mistake in not taking the cms1 database offline BEFORE renaming it? If so, is there a way to fix this, or should I start again? This cms1 database is a test, not the real thing, but I want to get the procedure nailed down before working on our live database. How would I move a copy of cms1 from physical to virtual, keeping cms1 on the virtual server, so both can exist side by side while I move data from certain tables of one to the other? I really hope I'm making sense--I've been fighting with this for two hours straight. Thanks for any suggestions. I'm not too experienced in this sort of thing; I know SQL reasonably well, but dealing with physical DB files, backups, etc is new to me.

Comment: Do you want to have two databases in your VM: Old and New?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need cms1 and cms1_old (where cms1_old is one server's copy) to exist on the same server. I know which tables in each have been altered and I just need to merge the two databases. Physically getting the cms1 database installed alongside a copy of itself is the tricky part since they share a name.

Comment: Name is not a problem. Question is: why would you do that? Just to have two DBs on the same server **to COMPARE** changes?

Comment: We eventually got it working! Rename the old one to cms1_old; detach it; rename the files; attach it, pointing to the new files. Select the backup file and restore it as cms1. That worked! As to why, we had two copies each with certain tables that had been modified independent of the other. I had to merge them into one db.